# How to Install Leaflet plugin for ionic 2

Tags: ionic2, leaflet

Anyone can help this? I am trying to import a leaflet plugin (https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet.markercluster) for ionic 2

Here is step which I did:

```
npm install leaflet.markercluster --save
```

I added leaflet like this:

`import * as L from 'leaflet'; import * as LL from 'leaflet.markercluster';`

And using it like this:

```
var markers = LL.markerClusterGroup();
```

i got an error TypeError:

> WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_2_leaflet_markercluster.markerClusterGroup is
>   not a function

Are there any ways to custom webpack to load plugin lib? Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Leaflet.markercluster plugin does not export itself the "standard" / UMD way.

When you import it, it only performs a *side effect*, i.e. it attaches itself to the `L` (Leaflet) global namespace. It does not return anything into your default import nor `LL` variable.

But you should be able to use it as if you had included it the "old school" way (i.e. through a `<script>` tag):

```js
var mcg = L.markerClusterGroup();
```

BTW, both Leaflet and Leaflet.markercluster perform side effects, so you would just need to import them this way:

```js
import 'leaflet'; // Creates a global L namespace.
import 'leaflet.markercluster'; // Attaches L.markerClusterGroup to global L.
```

Comment: Yes. We also need to install this to avoid typescript error.
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet-markercluster

Answer (score 2):

You need to use type declarations along with the module if you are using a javascript module.
For `leaflet.markercluster` it should be [here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@types/leaflet-markercluster).

After

```
npm install leaflet.markercluster --save
```

Do:

```
npm install --save-dev @types/leaflet-markercluster
```

Also ensure your `tsconfig.json` has the entry `"typeRoots": ["types"],`

Now it can be imported in your class.

```
import * as LL from 'leaflet-markercluster';
```