# webpack + leaflet plugin(s)

Tags: javascript, webpack, leaflet

I have a requireJs-based library, that exports object **T**, which holds Leaflet object **L**. And I have a Leaflet plugin ([this](https://github.com/shramov/leaflet-plugins), in my case, but valid for any other), which adds some functions to the global object **L**. And I have my module, where I want to use object **T** with extended **L**. Question: how to gracefully do it with Webpack? I could modify the plugin, to import L from the first library, but anyway don't understand how to plug it in to my module. And not sure that this is the best way.

P.S. I saw [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549529/how-to-install-leaflet-plugin-for-ionic-2) thread, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42638423/including-external-scripts-with-global-references-using-webpack) as well, but didn't find a good way there. I don't want to use additional < script> tags, and this is quite rambled to have statements like this:

```
import 'my.leflet.library';
import 'leaflet.plugin';
```

somewhere in the source - instead, I would prefer to add something to the configuration, that will extend **L** object right after 'my.leaflet.library' would be loaded, and any module, that would import 'my.leaflet.library' will have **T** with modified **L**. Is it possible?

Comment: Heh, trying to do this. It seems we need to connect these as external scripts adding it to global scope somehow. Mimicking script connected in right order as in browser.

Answer (score 1):

This is my webpack config for Vue (vue.config.js), you can probably adapt it for your needs.

```
const webpack = require('webpack')

module.exports = {
  configureWebpack: {
    plugins: [
      new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
        L: 'leaflet',
        'window.L': 'leaflet',
      })
    ],
  }
}
```